# Markov Chain Monte Carlo (python, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo, markov-chains

I am doing some research in physics, for which I need to analyze some data using a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC).  I tried to just write one myself but I keep coming across bugs when python/numpy rounds a very very small number down to zero.  Specifially when I need to do something like `numpy.exp(-1000)`.  That expression itself is part of a larger math equation so I can't just take the log of it.

I know that there are MCMC modules available for python and I have taken a look at some of them but am having trouble understanding the documentation for them to apply them.  Can anyone recommend one?  What I have is a column of data that I plug into a probability distribution. This distribution also has two other variables which I will be conducting random walks on and recording each step in the markov chain.  I will then need to make a histogram of each of those two variables based off the markov chain. I apologize if this question is too vague.  Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how exactly did you figure out that something is rounded down to 0? have you tried to increase precision of the numpy number type to 64 bit?

Comment: I know it's rounding down to 0 because I get the error: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log.  Where I am trying to do something like np.log(np.exp(-2000)). I have tried the np.float128() method but I am passing an array of numbers and float 128 can only do one at a time.

Comment: Can you just work with the log of the probability?

Answer (score 2):

Use higher-precision floats, if available on your system. For example, if you have `float128`:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.exp(np.float128(-1000)))  # 5.07595889755e-435
print(np.exp(np.float128(-10000)))  #  1.13548386531e-4343
```

Also see `longdouble`. It really depends on your operating system to what is supported and how.

You can convert arrays that require this precision and work with them with Numpy functions:

```
# Example array with 3 dimensions
d = np.random.uniform(-10000, -100, 24)
d.shape = (2, 3, 4)

# Cast to a higher precision
D = d.astype(np.float128)
np.exp(D[:,2])  # array([[4.263772e-4326, 4.3465066e-1474, ...
```

Comment: thank you for that suggestion and it almost fixes my problem.  The issue is that I'm not passing just one number into the float.  I'm passing a 1 dimensional array/coluumn into it.  Think of it more as np.exp(np.float128(d[:,3])).  I need to do the calculation for the entire array.  Is there a way to do something like this for the entire array at once? Or do I really need to do it element by element? thanks

Comment: @user1679198 see updated answer with `astype` to convert an array `d` to a higher-precision array `D`

Comment: Can't you use a log transform and avoid the `exp` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Use PyMC - it's great. Work through the tutorials and you should soon understand how to build a model.

http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/tutorial.html